# Rails 3: Create seed data from development database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a gem or a easy way to take the data from my Development DB and populate the seed.rb file in Rails 3?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is also [seed_dumper](https://github.com/kevTheDev/seed_dumper) which creates a seed file for you.

Comment: This is a much better solution

Answer (score 1):

In the past I [successfully used YamlDb](https://github.com/adamwiggins/yaml_db).

Answer (score 1):

[seed_dump](https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump) is working fine with Rails 4.

Example:

```
rake db:seed:dump MODELS=User APPEND=true
cat db/seeds.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **`MongoDB`** this is not currently supported for **`seed_dump`**.